# Toolbar Icons usage in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, icons, toolbar

I am porting a Linux Mono/GTK application to MS.NET/WPF. The application uses a toolbar, which I could have sworn VS had built in support for adding icons to through the WYSIWYG designer.

However, firstly, in the "Items" property, the add button is greyed out. I did some research and found that I could add `<Button></Button>` tags directly to the XAML, however, I still couldn't figure out how to add icons. I'd like to use the default Windows icons.

I then found that you had to add `<Image></Image>` tags to create typical icon based toolbar items, however, I didn't know where to find the default windows icons.

I read on a different stack exchange post that they are available in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033\VS2010ImageLibrary.zip`

However, I am stuck with VS Express edition, and according to the MSDN website this archive doesn't exist in VSE.

My question is this: is there any way to use the default Windows icons?

Also, is it possible I've missed something? How do most people handle toolbars?

Comment: If you are looking for icons you can use http://www.iconfinder.com/ for royalty free icons

Comment: I'd prefer to use the default icons if I can, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the system icons are not saved in the same place. They are spread across multiple dlls.

[List of Windows 7 icons stored in imageres.dll](http://windows7themes.net/list-of-windows-7-icons-stored-in-imageres-dll.html) is one such place. You can google for other stuff.

One you have the dll from which you want to create the WPF Image you can use [Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms603493.aspx) function after using [LoadIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)